# Position menu item right (commercial Kendo-UI for Angular components)

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

How can I position last n root menu items to the right? Let's say I want to position `Item 3`, and `Item 4` from this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/p0xhQ2QFtB5Z0ib3v9w2?p=preview&preview) at the end of menu row (on the right).
Something like this:
[image: Screenshot]

I don't see any API in [documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/menu/api/) that would describe such scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `margin-left: auto` on the third item.

```
.k-item.k-menu-item:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/IhNuEvI52yID0bCK